# Data Scrubbing using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-cleaning

So, I am cleaning a data set that has a timestamp as the first column, prices and volumes as the next two columns. I am trying to remove bad rows using several logic and then output a file that has all the bad ticks and another file that has all the good ticks. Every logic seems to work other than where I remove my duplicates. I end up getting lesser number of rows than I started with:

```
from datetime import datetime

to_sort = list()

noise= list()

line_counter=0

with open("hi.txt", 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        #splitting the lines using the delimiter comma
        splitted_line = line.strip().split(",")
        #stripping the time using the datetime function from the datetime library
        date1 = datetime.strptime(splitted_line[0],'%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S.%f')
        #creating columns for volume and price
        price = float(splitted_line[1])
        volume = int(splitted_line[2])
        #creating a tuple using date as first column, price as second and volume as third
        my_tuple=(date1,price,volume)

        #EDA shows that the prices are between 0 and 3000 and volume must be greater than zero
        if price > 0 and price<3000 and volume >0:
            to_sort.append(my_tuple)
        else:
            noise.append(my_tuple)
        line_counter +=1
        if line_counter %13==0:
        #removing duplicates using the set function
            sorted_signal=sorted(set(to_sort))


            with open ("true.txt","a")as s:
                for line in sorted_signal:
                    s.write(str(line[0])+","+ str(line[1])+","+str(line[2])+"\n")
                    to_sort=list()

            with open ("noise.txt","a")as n:
                for line in noise:
                    n.write(str(line[0])+","+ str(line[1])+","+str(line[2])+"\n")
                    noise=list()
```

Comment: If you're removing duplicates, it seems logical you'd end up with fewer items than you started with.

Comment: Since you're removing the duplicates shouldn't the result have less rows (assuming that there were duplicates present in the source)? If you could provide sample data, current result and expected result in the question it would be way easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: What I am trying to do is append everything that is a noise to a text file, even the duplicates. For instance if there are 2 duplicates, one ends up being the in true.txt and the other ends up being in noise.txt. How should  I proceed? Or, if there are 3 duplicates ... 2 of them end up being in noise and one of them end up being in true.txt